# Set NavigationBar Back to Default Values

Tags: objective-c, swift

I've changed several of the navigationBar properties for a view. However, I'd like to make sure everything reverts back to the default values once the view is unwinded or a new view is shown. Is there a way to reset all values?

Changed Values:

```
    // set status bar white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default

    // make navigation bar clear/transparent
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
    let titleDict: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = titleDict
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else needs this:

```
func setNavigationBarDefaults() {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    setNavigationBarDefaults()
}
```